# mySQL Combining the results of searches

Tags: php, mysql

My problem is:
I have a dbase query (A) with events_A with today date

```
 $STH_1 = $DBH_R->query("SELECT table_name                        
                         FROM information_schema.tables                        
                        WHERE table_name                        
                         LIKE 'v_c_ei\_9%' ");
$stmts_1 = array();

while (($row_1 = $STH_1 -> fetch_assoc()) !== null){

$table_name = $row_1['table_name'];
$stmts_1[] = sprintf("
                      SELECT *
                        FROM $table_name 
                       WHERE date_time = $today_date                
              ");                    
}

$stmt_1 = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1);  
$stmt_1 .= "\nORDER BY date_time ASC";  

$STH_5_2 = $DBH_R->query($stmt_1);

while (($row_5_2 = $STH_5_2 -> fetch_assoc()) !== null) {   }
```

and I can display the results from this in the table_A.

But I have a dbase query (B) with events_B with today date

```
$table_name_2 = 'v_c_e';
$STH_e = $DBH_R->query("
                        SELECT *                       
                          FROM `$table_name_2`                        
                         WHERE date_time = $today_date                   
                      "); 

while (($row_e = $STH_e -> fetch_assoc()) !== null) {   }
```

and I can display the results from this in the table_B.

The source tables for the first query and for the second query have only one common column - date_time.

What I must to do (and how) to display events_A and events_B in one table (ORDER BY date_time ASC)?  - and for future - how add events_C (f.ex. similar to events_B)?

// I know that after all I need to format the data so that they look similar and it can be displayed in one table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear from your question whether you want to *join* the results - that is, the information from both tables is related in that two records sharing a `date_time` should be the same event - or unrelated.

If it is the latter, you cannot combine them meaningfully; you effectively have two different schemas.

If the information in tables A and B refers to the same events, and the `date_time` is a unique key, then you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM events_A, events_B WHERE events_A.date_time=events_B.date_time;
```

... or the like.

I think, from the query you built in PHP, you're not very strong on the features of SQL and when you would want to use them. It might be worth reading something like [this guide](http://philip.greenspun.com/sql/) to get a better handle on what should be done in the database rather than in PHP code before proceeding.

Comment: 1. the table for event_A is virtual, not real one in dbase. 2. the informations of event_A (vegetables) and event_B (minerals) are different - only this one column (date_time) is with similar information. 3. date_time is used only to rank as a function of time (listing ASC)

Comment: maybe something like: $STH_5_2 = $DBH_R->query("SELECT * FROM `$table_name_2` WHERE date_time = $today_date UNION $stmt_1 ORDER BY date_time ASC"); // but result is empty ...

Comment: ha, generally, time(date_time) can be different for events_A and events_B but .. date(date_time) must be the same :))